# geo-disaster recovery azure function app which has only one timer function

Tags: azure-functions, disaster-recovery

How do you design geo-disaster recovery azure function app which has only one timer function?

I did all research I could over the internet and I did not find a suitable answer.
I can not make use of Azure front door or Traffic manager to route the calls is it not an HTTPS trigger.
One option is to monitor a disaster and enabling function in a second region maually.
How to do it programmatically?